# Perl - enhance code to recursively count files

Tags: perl

I am new to Perl and am trying to learn the language but am having a difficult time doing something that I think is probably simple.

I have been able to get a script working that will count the just the number of files in a directory.  I would like to enhance the script to recursively count all files in any sub directories also.  I have searched and found a few different options for GLOB and File::Find, but have not been able to get them to work.

My current code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Path::Class;

# Set variables

my $count = 0;  # Set count to start at 0
my $dir = dir('p:'); # p/

# Iterate over the content of p:pepid content db/pepid ed
while (my $file = $dir->next) {   


    next if $file->is_dir();    # See if it is a directory and skip


    print $file->stringify . "\n";   # Print out the file name and path
    $count++   # increment count by 1 for every file counted

}


print "Number of files counted " . $count . "\n";
```

Can anyone help me enhance this code to recursively search any sub directories as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [File::Find](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) module is your friend for recursive kinds of operations. Here's a simple script that counts files:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Cwd;
use File::Find;

my $dir = getcwd; # Get the current working directory

my $counter = 0;
find(\&wanted, $dir);
print "Found $counter files at and below $dir\n";

sub wanted {
    -f && $counter++; # Only count files
}
```